# What is the definition of font size?

Tags: typography

I tried to search the Internet for a definition but I didn't find much. So, what is the definition of font size? For instance, what makes a 10 pixel font a 10 pixel font?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @OGHaza What do you measure to determine a font's size?

Comment: I think (not certain enough to post an answer) that it is the distance between the top of the highest glyph and the bottom of the lowest glyph. I've found fonts appear to greatly vary in size though (i.e 1 font at 32px can look a lot smaller than another).

Comment: @OGHaza Yes, but that is probably because of the difference in x-height.

Comment: what you measure is not fixed and can vary from font to font, the maker of the font can overrule convention if they so wish.

Comment: @aug But I'm still left thinking that given you know a font is set at 12px you still can't know how tall it will be. (which joojaa has just confirmed)

Comment: @OGHaza but you can type something and measure it. See: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/any-automated-system-to-compute-the-linear-length-of-a-letters-in-a-word-or-ph

Comment: @joo, but if measuring told you the font size, [these 2 lowercase Ls](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d4YO4.png) would be different font sizes (both size 96px). I don't see how that link applies to font-size - it seems to talk about horizontal length of a string.

Comment: @OGHaza, yes thats it the size value is meaningless if the fontmaker does not comply or know what the height should be. Incidenttally all the outlined methods in my answer give height i just discard that result. You can then do it for the whole alphabet. Anyway there can be good reasons to not comply with convention such as keeping widths of the lines same across different variants of a font family.

Comment: @joojaa, ah sorry I didn't actually see you had an answer there. Yeah I agree with everything you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as the maximum height of a line of text. Glyphs may not be as big as the maximum height, so yeah ... some 10px fonts are not real 10px but 9px or 8px.

Answer (score 1):

A font is designed in terms of a design space, typically 1000 x 1000 units for Type 1 and PostScript-derived OpenType fonts, an order of 2 (1024 x 1024, 2048 x 2048, &c.) for TrueType.

A 10 point font is a font set so that the design-space is 10 points (one em-square) wide and 10 points (one em-square) tall, so if one had a font which had a character which completely filled the square design space that character would be ten points wide and ten points tall.

More details on this in any decent text on type design.

Comment: So the font size is the (vertical) distance between the ascender line and the descender line?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the answer to try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In Typography the definition for font size is: the size of text characters, measured in units called points (pts); a point is equal to 1/72 inch.

In typography, a point is the smallest whole unit of measure, being a subdivision of the larger pica. It is commonly abbreviated as pt. The point has long been the usual unit for measuring font size and leading and other minute items on a printed page.

Comment: The fact that the size of a font is defined by the size of its characters doesn't clarify anything for me.